# Is is possible to control %QX0.0 LED light through OpenPLC ModBus?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, plc, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

just started my OpenPLC journey and created my first project using the tutorial and was wondering is It possible to turn on the LED through a packet sent to the default ModBus server port 502 instead of pressing the button physically? I have been going in circles and would be happy to get any help and direction! Thank you in advance!

Setup:
1 X RPI 3 b+
1 X LED
2 X Button

Raspberry pi is installed with OpenPLC and project uploaded to OpenPLC. light turns on and off with the press of a button once PLC server is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  According to [OpenPLC's documentation](http://www.openplcproject.com/scada) the Modbus Slave supports coil registers with read/write access.

Now that you know you are not spinning your wheels in vain here are a couple of things to check.

- verify that your PLC logic is not telling that output to turn off which will override the Modbus request
- verify that your Modbus master (the device which is sending your packet) supports functions 5 &/or 15